# PHP and .Net Connector connection pooling conflict on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, azure

We have a Web Application on azure that is intended to be a backend for a videogame.

The backend is partially PHP and partially .Net, and it connects to a MySQL Database on `clearDb` that has 15 connections available.

When connecting intensively from my and my colleague's account we often see a block in database communications that takes a while to solve (or a server reset).

Is there a possibility that the connection pooling from one of the two frameworks (for instance .net) is choking the other by taking all connections in its pool and thus preventing the other (PHP) to establish even a single connection?

Comment: I must add that we are trying to give MaxPoolSize parameter to both PHP and .Net connections to see if we can overcome the problem

Comment: Connection pooling occurs in the client, not the database so the scenario you are describing is most probable. Try to give a low max pool size so that no one can have 15 connections to the pool.

Comment: Thank you Tasos, that was the case. A bug in our .Net code was chocking the Php client.

Comment: Glad I helped. I posted it as an answer, it will be more visible for anyone reading this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection pooling occurs in the client, not the database so the scenario you are describing is most probable. Try to give a low max pool size so that no one can have 15 connections to the pool